How to check self intersection while editing the polygon on react-leaflet
How to check self intersection while editing the polygon on react-leaflet?
I want to get the warning while dragging the polygon edit handlers.
i am editing single polygon at a time
const onEditClick = (layerData) => {
  layerData.editing.enable();
};

i want the intersection warning on editing polygon
while dragging the edit handlers i want to check the intersection and give warning and come back to to the last valid position
